# $routeChangeSuccess is not working with ngNewRouter AngularJS 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, router

I am moving from **AngularJS 1.3** to **AngularJS 1.4**. And this time I am using **AngularJS** new route e.g. `ngNewRouter` which is introduced in **AngularJS 1.4**.

My sample code is as below:

```
var versionModule = ng.module('test', ['ngNewRouter']);
versionModule.controller('TestController', ['$rootScope', '$router', function ($rootScope, $router) {
    var version = this;
    $router.config([
        {
            path: '/',
            redirectTo: '/home'
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: 'home'
        }
    ]);
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        console.log("This line is not getting printed ever.");
    });
}]);
```

Routing is working fine but **$routeChangeSuccess** is not getting called ever :( .

Might be **$routeChangeSuccess** lister will be called with `ngRoute` module only, and I am using `ngNewRouter` instead of `ngRoute`. If its true then which lister should I bind in place of **$routeChangeSuccess** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Hooks available for change detection. I think you should listen activate hook on controller where you want to detect change. You can look [here](http://angular.github.io/router/lifecycle) for more detail.